# BE on shared folder that require authentication

Tags: ms-access

In a very large LAN I have shared folders protected by LDAP auth.
I've put my BE on a shared folder and enabled the due users to access that folder.
In the FE the tables are linked to the BE ones so before I can open the FE I have to previously open (doubleclick) the shared folder (in order to provide username and password) and then close it. Very ugly.
How can I open an FE linked to a BE placed in a protected folder without having to open that folder first ?

Thanx in advance
Marco

Answer (score 1):

I solved. After opening the FE I show a form that asks for username and password then I pass that credentials to the following function. If it returns FALSE the credentials provided was not right.

```
Public Function RemoteLogin(Ute As String, Pw As String, RemotePath As String) As Boolean
Dim Str1 As String

'  to disable the credentials : Str1 = "net use " & RemotePath & "/delete"

   Str1 = "net use " & RemotePath & " /user:" & Ute & " " & Pw
   Shell "cmd.exe /c " & Str1, vbHide
   WaitForSeconds (2)
   On Error Resume Next
   RemoteLogin = ((GetAttr(RemotePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory)

End Function
```

(RemotePath is something like "\\fileServer\SharedFolder")

I had to put a delay of 2 seconds because in medium-large LAN i takes time to propagate (we use SAMBA and LDAP).
After the delay I had to test the openess of the path because Shell does not return any result neither if the provided password was correct nor if it wasn't.

HTH

Marco

Answer (score 0):

And here is a better solution where a syncronous version of the Shell command is used (suggested by @Alex from masterdrive.it). No need to force a delay of 2 seconds here.

```
Public Function RemoteLogin(Ute As String, Pw As String, RemotePath As String) As Boolean
Dim Str1 As String

   Str1 = "net use " & RemotePath & " /user:" & Ute & " " & Pw
   Str1 = "cmd.exe /c " & Str1
   Call MyShell(Str1, vbHide, True)
   On Error Resume Next
   RemoteLogin = ((GetAttr(RemotePath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory)

End Function 

Sub MyShell(ByVal Percorso As String, ByVal windowstyle As Integer, ByVal Attendi As Boolean)
   Dim wshell As Object
   Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
   wshell.Run Percorso, windowstyle, Attendi
   Set wshell = Nothing
End Sub
```